# How to set different font-size within one cell by using openpyxl?

Tags: python, fonts, openpyxl

Here is I using now, but I hope it can set different font-size within one cell.

For example:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font

wb = Workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active

sheet['A1'].value = 'Apple Banana'
sheet['A1'].font = Font(size=16)

wb.save('test123.xlsx')
```

Is that possible to set 'Apple' font-size to 10 and set 'Banana' font-size to 20 within a  cell?

Comment: No, not at the moment. But I believe support for rich text is in the works.

Comment: This is covered in the openpyxl documentation.

Comment: If running on windows and openpyxl is not a must then you can do this with xlwings 'character' class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Branch 3.1](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/tree/branch/3.1) has support for rich text. Of course, it's a dev branch so don't rely on it. It could change before it's released.

```py
import sys

# The directory below should contain another directory "openpyxl"
sys.path.insert(0,"C:\Users\Sleve McDichael\Desktop\openpyxl-branch-3.2")

import openpyxl
from openpyxl.cell.rich_text import TextBlock, CellRichText
from openpyxl.cell.text import InlineFont

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

size_10 = InlineFont(sz=10)
size_20 = InlineFont(sz=20)

ws["A1"] = CellRichText([TextBlock(font=size_10, text="Apple"), TextBlock(font=size_20, text="Banana")])

wb.save(r"C:\Users\Sleve McDichael\Desktop\richtext spreadsheed.xlsx")
```

The spreadsheet looks like this:

[image: spreadsheet]

Have a look at:

- [`\openpyxl\cell\tests\test_rich_text.py`](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.2/openpyxl/cell/tests/test_rich_text.py)
- [`\openpyxl\cell\rich_text.py`](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.2/openpyxl/cell/rich_text.py)

Comment: 3.2 really isn't ready for public consumption.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay,
It works by using Branch3.1 or 3.2 with Python3.10.
But In Python3.8, It'll fail on wb.save('xxx.xlsx'), and shows error msg 
'TextBlock' object has no attribute 'name'. 
How can I solve that? I need to use Python3.8 to build exe to run in win7.

Comment: Sorry, as Charlie said, it's not ready for public consumption. It comes with no guarantees of working.

Comment: @Shihau (or anyone else seeing this) make sure you have `lxml` package installed. [Comment thread here](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1842) notes the root problem is with etree and not lxml

Answer (score 0):

How to do this with XLWINGS

```
import xlwings as xw


wb = xw.Book('foo.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheets('Sheet1')

# ws.range(1, x).characters[i:i+2].api.Font.Subscript = True
ws.range(1, 1).value = "AppleAndBanana"
ws.range(1, 1).font.size = 10
ws.range(1, 1).characters[0:5].font.size = 32
ws.range(1, 1).characters[8:15].font.size = 16

wb.save()
wb.close()
```